# Build file in Sublime Text 3 to invoke JUnit5 tests

Tags: java, build, sublimetext3, junit5

I am trying to configure **Sublime Text 3**'s **RunJava.sublime-build** file to add an option to execute **JUnit 5** test on **Mac OS X**.

The following works for me from the Mac OS X terminal window:

`$ java -jar /Users/pavlomaistrenko/Documents/Junit1.6/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar -cp /Users/pavlomaistrenko/Documents/GitHub/SvitlanaMo/Java01/ --scan-classpath`

My **RunJava.sublime-build** configuration file is:

```
{
    "selector": "source.java",
    "file_patterns": "*.java",
    "working_dir": "$file_path",
    "shell_cmd": "javac -cp .:/Users/pavlomaistrenko/Documents/GitHub/SvitlanaMo/Java01/:/Users/pavlomaistrenko/Documents/Junit1.6/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar $file_name",
    "variants": [
        {
            "name": "Run class.jar",
            "shell_cmd": "java -cp .:/Users/pavlomaistrenko/Documents/GitHub/SvitlanaMo/Java01/:/Users/pavlomaistrenko/Documents/Junit1.6/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar $file_base_name"
        },

        {
            "name": "JavaDoc",
            "shell_cmd": "mkdir -p documentation && javadoc -header \"<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'></script>\" -d documentation *.java"
        },

        {
            "name": "JAR",
            "cmd": "javac '$realpath$file' && echo \"Main-Class: $file_base_name\" > Manifest.txt && jar cfm $file_base_name.jar Manifest.txt *.class && rm *.class && java -jar $file_base_name.jar"
        },

        {
            "name": "JUnit5",
            "cmd": "java -jar /Users/pavlomaistrenko/Documents/Junit1.6/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar -cp $file_path --scan-classpath"
        }

    ]
}
```

Instead of full JUnit 5 output I just get `[Finished in X.Xs]`.

Does JUnit get executed? If so, where is the output?

P.S. I have read Sublime is not a perfect environment for Java, but still.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are doing to trigger the unit tests is either using the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> keyboard shortcut or selecting **`Tools → Build`** from the menu. The way Sublime's build systems work, this will only trigger the initial `"shell_cmd"` command. The way to run one of the variants is to use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> or select **`Tools → Build With…`**. This will display a dropdown with all the different variants available. Selecting **`JUnit5`** should run your unit tests as specified.

Comment: MattDMo, thank you very much, I do choose the correct build option, but it does not give any output to the Sublime's console. Just `Finished in SOMEs`.  So, while it takes several second to run, I suspect Junit gets executed, but, for some reason, Sublime Text does not show it, Alternative possibility, it does not get run at all.

Comment: Try opening the console (**`View → Show Console`**) and see if anything has printed there.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. I finally figured out the problem. It was in the build file. I will post the answer shortly. P.S. Instead, I've got a problem with the build settings for javac. I'll post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found out a working build configuration for JUnit5. Here is the snippet:

```
{
    "name": "JUnit5 the folder",
    "env": { "user_path": "/Users/pavlomaistrenko/Documents",
     "junit5":  "Junit1.6/junit-platform-console-standalone-1.6.2.jar",
     "project_path": "GitHub/SvitlanaMo/Java01/"
   },
    "shell_cmd": "java -jar \\$user_path/\\$junit5 -cp .:$file_path --scan-classpath"
},
```

Note the double escaping of *$* with two backslashes *\\* for Mac OS. The *env* variables are not expanded by Sublime, rather they are set as environment variables for this particular call of java loader (and then expanded by the shell.) See [Use custom variables in Sublime Text build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187463/use-custom-variables-in-sublime-text-build-system) for explanation.